# Why is my UIpickerView now taking my builds 3 hours to complete?

Tags: swift, xcode, compilation

I have created an application in xcode 10.3 with swift to effectivly work out out 9 vairables to give 5 results. To select the variables it is though a 9 wheel picckerview.

I have added all the variables in some of the example code below, and it runs perfectly giving the correct results. However the build time is taking up to THREE hours... is this something I have done wrong?

As the code below shows as soon as ths didSelectRow starts to get busy, then the build time is extreme. There are about 300+ 'if' statements covering the variables from pickerView.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let runway = runwaydataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let flap = flapdataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
        let wght = weightdataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]
        let alt = altdataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 3)]
        let wind = winddataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 4)]
        let slope = slopedataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 5)]
        let temp = tempdataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 6)]
        let vref = vrefdataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 7)]
        let rev = revdataSource[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 8)]

        runwaylabel.text = "\(runway)"
        flaplabel.text = "\(flap)°"
        weightlabel.text = "\(wght)kg"
        altlabel.text = "\(alt)ft"
        windlabel.text = "\(wind)kts"
        slopelabel.text = "\(slope)°"
        templabel.text = "\(temp)°C"
        vreflabel.text = "\(vref)kts"
        revlabel.text = "\(rev)"

        // :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        // :::::::::: FLAP REF ADJUSTMENT CALCULATION (DRY) ::::::::::::
        // :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        if runwaylabel.text == "Dry" && flaplabel.text == "20°" {
            flaprefadjust.text = "\(1465)"
            flaprefadjustmax.text = "\(2000)"
            flaprefadjust4.text = "\(2590)"
            flaprefadjust3.text = "\(3050)"
            flaprefadjust2.text = "\(3340)"
            flaprefadjust1.text = "\(3595)"
        }

        else if runwaylabel.text == "Dry" && flaplabel.text == "25°" {
            flaprefadjust.text = "\(1360)"
            flaprefadjustmax.text = "\(1820)"
            flaprefadjust4.text = "\(2335)"
            flaprefadjust3.text = "\(2745)"
            flaprefadjust2.text = "\(3005)"
            flaprefadjust1.text = "\(3240)"
        }
        else if runwaylabel.text == "Dry" && flaplabel.text == "30°" {
            flaprefadjust.text = "\(1300)"
            flaprefadjustmax.text = "\(1705)"
            flaprefadjust4.text = "\(2175)"
            flaprefadjust3.text = "\(2545)"
            flaprefadjust2.text = "\(2805)"
            flaprefadjust1.text = "\(3035)"
        }

        else if runwaylabel.text == "Good" && flaplabel.text == "20°" {
            flaprefadjust.text = "\(2035)"
            flaprefadjustmax.text = "\(2115)"
            flaprefadjust4.text = "\(2595)"
            flaprefadjust3.text = "\(3050)"
            flaprefadjust2.text = "\(3340)"
            flaprefadjust1.text = "\(3595)"
        }

        else if runwaylabel.text == "Good" && flaplabel.text == "25°" {
            flaprefadjust.text = "\(1865)"
            flaprefadjustmax.text = "\(1935)"
            flaprefadjust4.text = "\(2350)"
            flaprefadjust3.text = "\(2745)"
            flaprefadjust2.text = "\(3005)"
            flaprefadjust1.text = "\(3240)"
        }
        else if runwaylabel.text == "Good" && flaplabel.text == "30°" {
            flaprefadjust.text = "\(1775)"
            flaprefadjustmax.text = "\(1835)"
            flaprefadjust4.text = "\(2180)"
            flaprefadjust3.text = "\(2545)"
            flaprefadjust2.text = "\(2805)"
            flaprefadjust1.text = "\(3035)"
        }


        let flaprefadjustresult = NSString(string: flaprefadjust.text!).doubleValue
        let flaprefadjustresultmax = NSString(string: flaprefadjustmax.text!).doubleValue
        let flaprefadjustresult4 = NSString(string: flaprefadjust4.text!).doubleValue
        let flaprefadjustresult3 = NSString(string: flaprefadjust3.text!).doubleValue
        let flaprefadjustresult2 = NSString(string: flaprefadjust2.text!).doubleValue
        let flaprefadjustresult1 = NSString(string: flaprefadjust1.text!).doubleValue

        // :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        // :::::::::: WEIGHT ADJUSTMENT CALCULATIONS (DRY) :::::::::::::
        // :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        if runwaylabel.text == "Dry" && flaplabel.text == "20°" && weightlabel.text == "340,000kg" {
            weightadjust.text = "\(630)"
            weightadjustmax.text = "\(450)"
            weightadjust4.text = "\(630)"
            weightadjust3.text = "\(810)"
            weightadjust2.text = "\(900)"
            weightadjust1.text = "\(1170)"
        }
        else if runwaylabel.text == "Dry" && flaplabel.text == "20°" && weightlabel.text == "335,000kg"{
            weightadjust.text = "\(595)"
            weightadjustmax.text = "\(425)"
            weightadjust4.text = "\(595)"
            weightadjust3.text = "\(765)"
            weightadjust2.text = "\(850)"
            weightadjust1.text = "\(1105)"
        }
        else if runwaylabel.text == "Dry" && flaplabel.text == "20°" && weightlabel.text == "330,000kg"{
            weightadjust.text = "\(560)"
            weightadjustmax.text = "\(400)"
            weightadjust4.text = "\(560)"
            weightadjust3.text = "\(720)"
            weightadjust2.text = "\(800)"
            weightadjust1.text = "\(1040)"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

does commenting out this method make the project compile faster?

aside from that, there are numerous bad practices in the code above, 
your logic should probably be separated into some sort of a 'controller object',
all those decelerations and initializations seem very constant and don't need to occur every time this method is called.

the string comparison to "30o" etc. feels weird, why not work with the underlying values instead?

you could read a bit on the topic of 'pattern matching switch statements' in swift.

a nice enum will clean this code up nicely.